# Remove time in date time function?

Tags: python, django, templates, datetime

I have a variable  `{{value.time}}` in this value executes

```
March 22, 2013, 2:30 a.m
```

But I want to remove the  `2:30 a.m` (time) for this value in my templates file. How could I do this?

Comment: How about [strftime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put date as extension

```
{{ value.time.date }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,date
>>> date_str = 'March 22, 2013, 2:30 a.m'
>>> date_str = date_str.replace('a.m','AM')
>>> formatter_string = "%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p" 
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, formatter_string)
>>> date_object = datetime_object.date() # date object without '2:30 AM'
>>> date_object
datetime.date(2013, 3, 22)
>>> formatter_string = "%B %d, %Y" 
>>> datetime_string = datetime.strftime(date_object, formatter_string)
>>> datetime_string
'March 22, 2013'
```